# Is $\mathrm{End}-\{0\}=\mathrm{Aut}$ for derivation Lie algebra?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lie-algebras

> Is it true that every nonzero endomorphism of Lie $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]\partial_{x_1}\oplus\ldots\oplus\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]\partial_{x_n}$ is an automorphism?

As I know a positive answer to question implies the Jacobian conjecture for $\mathbb{A}_n$.

So is it equivalent or a stronger result than JC?

**Idea of proof that (positive answer to Question) $\Rightarrow$ JC**

If $(F_1,\ldots, F_n)$ is a set of polynomials with constant nonzero Jacobian, then $\mathbb{C}[F_1,\ldots, F_n]\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ is subalgebra. It can be shown that the constant Jacobian means that each derivation from $\mathbb{C}[F_1,\ldots, F_n]$ can be uniquely continued to a derivation of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$. So we have the inclusion $\text{Der}(\mathbb{C}[F_1,\ldots, F_n])\to\text{Der}(\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n])$. If the main question has a positive answer, then this inclusion is surjective and there are derivations $D_1,\ldots, D_n$ of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ with $D_i|_{\mathbb{C}[F_1,\ldots, F_n]}=\partial_{F_i}$. We know that $F_i$ are slices of $D_i$, so it is enough to check that $D_i$ are locally nilpotent commuting derivations. Since $D_i$ are locally nilpotent on $\mathbb{C}[F_1,\ldots, F_n]$ one can prove that $\text{ad}D_i|_{\text{Der}(\mathbb{C}[F_1,\ldots, F_n])}$ are locally nilpotent derivations of $\text{Der}(\mathbb{C}[F_1,\ldots, F_n])$, so (from Question statement) $\text{ad}D_i$ is locally nilpotent on $\text{Der}(\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n])$. Thus one can prove that $D_i$ is locally nilpotent on $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ and the $D_i$ are locally nilpotent with slices $F_i$ which commute with each other, so we have JC.

Comment: What is the Lie algebra structure? For instance, what is $[x_1,\partial _{x_1}]$?

Comment: There is no elements $x_i$ in this Lie algebra. For $a, b$, $[a, b] = ab - ba$

Comment: @abx $x_1$ is not in the Lie algebra. The Lie algebra structure is the commutator: $P(x)\partial $ is the operator $Q(x)\mapsto P(x)\partial x$, and the bracket is the commutator of operators $[T,U]Q=TUQ-UTQ$.

Comment: Oh, OK, that was stupid, sorry.

Comment: But isn't $\operatorname{ad}(\partial_{x_1}) $  an endomorphism which kills the $\partial _{x_i}$ for $i>1$?

Comment: @abx, that's a derivation of the lie algebra. U can exponentiate it (bc it's loc nilpotent) to an endom, but ofc this will be an aut

Comment: Oh sure, I am stupid again. Thanks.

Comment: As I know Jacobian conjecture is a consequence of this question. So is it equivalent to Jacobian conjecture for $\mathbb{A}^n$?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why does a positive answer imply the Jacobian conjecture? Also, do you know the answer for $n=1$?

Comment: For $n=1$ it is obviously true since the only nilpotent elements of derivation algebra are $\mathbb{C}\partial_x$.

Comment: Actually I did the "exercise" for $n=1$. I had to be careful because the image of an ad-locally-nilpotent element by an (non-surjective) endomorphism is possibly not ad-locally-nilpotent, but in the present case it can be checked by hand, and eventually $\partial_x$ is mapped to a nonzero multiple of itself, which easily implies that the subspace of elements of degree $\le n$ is stable for all $n$, and hence we can run the "injective implies surjective" argument.

Comment: For each commutative algebra $A$ we have that ad of $D\in\text{Der}(A)$ is locally nilpotent if and only if $D$ is locally nilpotent derivation of $A$. It is because for each $a\in A$ we have $(\text{ad}D)(aD) = [D, aD] = (Da)D$ and so $(\text{ad}D)^n(aD) = (D^na)D$ so if for some $n$ it is known that $(\text{ad}D)^n(aD) = 0$ then $(D^na)D = 0$ and $D^na=0$.

Comment: We also need $A$ to be of finite trancendence degree. If $D$ is locally nilpotent then for each $a\in A$ and each $U\in\text{Der}(A)$, $(\text{ad}D)^n(U)(a) = \ldots+D^iUD^{n-i}(a)+\ldots = 0$ for $n$ large. So since we know that $A$ has finite trancendence degree so $(\text{ad}D)^n(U)=0$ for large $n$ for each $U$.